# What is happening at the motor with those protection elements: ferrites, varistors, capacitors and diodes?

Tags: dc-motor, circuit-protection, motordriver

Could someone please explain what is happening here? How do the individual elements on the right side of the driver at the motor help the motor driver circuit and motor? How is the correct value of inductance for the motor calculated?

I wanted to drive the DC motor using this driver. I understand the ferrites are for EMC. The varistors are for over voltage protection and the inductance to smooth out the current for the motor. I have no idea about the diodes, probably for back EMF as flyback. Please correct if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? What have you found out so far?

Comment: No it is not home work. I wanted to drive the DC motor using this driver. I understand the ferrites are for emc. The varistors are for over voltage protection and the inductance to smooth out the current for the motor. But the diodes i have no idea, probably for back EMF as flyback? please correct if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: You should add your info in the comments to your question.  This will allow people to clarify misconceptions and create a valuable answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Done. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this schematic from?

Comment: @TimWilliams This schematic was from one of my mutual friends whom I dont have contact with anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't speak for the originator's intent.  I can only analyze what is given.  Then:

At a glance, none of the manufacturer's documents suggest any of these output network components.

The only thing I can see being of use, is the schottky diodes.  These have slightly lower voltage drop than the body diodes in the H-bridge, perhaps saving chip dissipation when using passive free-wheeling mode.  But a full H-bridge of diodes is not shown (i.e. from OUTn to VM), so the savings is only partial, and bEMF capacity is not increased.

And that's not much use, because the chip is wired for direct external control; you can do current mode control or whatever you like based on the current sense signal, and do full synchronous switching (current flows through MOSFET channel, not body diode).  Normally, I would guess, you only go Hi-Z when the motor is shutting off completely; so, this would only be done infrequently, and the power dissipation is minimal.

Note that bEMF is only ever a concern if the motor can be spun, externally, faster than the supply voltage corresponding to that RPM (assuming PM type motor: PMDC, BLDC, synchronous, stepper..).  This is N/A for series-wound and induction types.

The type of varistor is not shown, but given the supply is 5V and the rating is 5.5V, they will only ever serve as dummy capacitance.  So can be reduced to the series combination with the capacitors.

Also, varistors are particularly useless in such low voltages anyway; a typical 5.5VDC part has a clamping voltage of over 20V (see [Littelfuse ZA datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/varistors/littelfuse_varistor_za_datasheet.pdf.pdf) for example).

The arrangement suggests an R+C damping or snubbing network, but varistors are not resistors, no matter how much people like to draw them that way, or describe them as "variable resistors" ("varistor" for short).  The initial resistance is very high, and only drops low (in terms of dynamic resistance) in breakdown.  It's a semiconductor breakdown curve, just softer than that of a TVS proper, due to material structure.

The ferrite beads (Wurth 742792641 is a 300Ω 2A 0603 ferrite bead) may be intended for filtering, but will saturate by perhaps 50mA, so as soon as any motor current starts to flow, their impedance drops substantially.  (This is typical for parts of this size, anyway; Wurth does not provide any data under DC bias for this part.)  Ferrite beads make poor filters in general, especially when power is involved; their greatest value is in introducing a modest impedance, and especially, a lossy one, to dampen resonances.

Perhaps if there was an unusually long route length (trace inductance goes roughly as 1nH/mm of length) between chip and MOV/caps or diodes, the damping value of the ferrite beads would show; or, at least by intent (many are unaware of the low saturation current of ferrite beads, so may use them with the right intent in places like this, but never follow up to measure if they're actually doing anything at all, and as a result, never discover this characteristic).

So in summary, I would remove the ferrite beads, varistors and capacitors, and probably the diodes.  Possibly the diodes would be useful in some applications, but mind that their capacitance also increases switching loss, a concern if you're running at a fairly high switching frequency (which might be of interest given the final point below).

Which, switching frequency would probably be under 200kHz.  This chip isn't clear on maximum frequency, but it seems unlikely that many internal functions would be useful much higher than that, and probably 50-100kHz would be preferred.

Finally, the 120uH inductors seem the most useful, but are missing a few steps depending.

The datasheet shows direct driving a motor, which is acceptable when the motor is nearby (short wiring length), and preferably the motor's case is grounded to the circuit so the switching noise has a quick return path.  This reduces emissions.  (Preferably the wiring would be shielded, the shield being hard RF-grounded to controller ground plane and motor case.  Such measures are probably not required for commercial EMC levels, but may be needed for longer lengths not using filtering for some reason, or more stringent test levels.)

Motors have substantial inductance, which acts to filter the square voltage into a triangular current waveform, and thus PWM can regulate current as desired.  If the motor is nearby, the 120uH inductors wouldn't seem to be very useful.

If the motor is to be at a distance, preferably the switching noise should be filtered locally.  Connect a series inductor at the chip, then put a C || (R+C) in shunt (to GND) after it.  Repeat for both phases.  This puts a lowpass filter at the switching output.  With the cutoff frequency several times below the PWM frequency, most of the switching noise and ripple will be filtered, and the output wires can be practically any length, no shielding required.

The R+C damping is necessary because the point of PWM is to be able to shift the mean ("DC") level over time.  Which means energy can be present near the cutoff frequency, which will excite the LC resonance of the filter.  Alternately: a filter is meaningless without some termination resistance, and the inverter is very low so we don't get anything there, and the motor is very high (inductive), also no use.  So we apply a damping resistance, for frequencies near cutoff (in the "transition band").  Finally, we don't want to dissipate DC power, hence using an R+C in parallel with the C.

I don't know that 120uH is the correct value for any particular application, but it seems in the right ballpark for this, anyway.  It should be rated for DC current, and saturation greater than peak current.

The capacitor values are determined by the filter impedance and cutoff frequency.  Generally the impedance should be near the operating point, so, 5V 2A or 2.5Ω.  Say PWM is chosen at 50kHz: cutoff should be much less, say 1/3 or 16kHz.  Then L = Zo / (2 pi Fo) = 25uH (choose 22-33uH), and C = 1 / (2 pi Zo Fo) = 4uF (choose 3.3-4.7uF).  The R+C should have R = Zo and Cs > 2.5 C, so, 10uF or so.  These can be X7R ceramic chip, probably larger than 0805 so the C(V) curve remains fairly flat over the operating voltage range.

Comment: Highly appreciate your time and effort, Tim. Learnt quite a lot. I got everything except the last part. When you say 1/3 of 50 kHz as an example cutoff level for the frequency, you mean only 16 kHz is passed and above that level will be attenuated? or 16 kHz more than 50 kHz, that is everything above 66 kHz is attenuated? we only need the noise frequency to be filtered right? not anything in the 50 kHz required/ applied PWM frequency?

Comment: 1/3 of, or 16kHz Fc. You can check the calculations, 1/(2 pi sqrt(LC)), 4.7uF and 33uH would give 12.8kHz. It's not a hard cutoff, it's only a 2nd order filter, but the important part is the input inductive reactance above Fc for smooth switching, and the eventual attenuation of harmonics to avoid emitting radio interference.

Comment: Ok. I will try it out and also measure how it makes difference. By the way could you please provide me some reference/ articles to gain more theoretical insight into the basics behind this phenomenon? or how do i start with learning about this? Thanks.

Comment: Far too many references to list (I also tend to accumulate knowledge from various bits over time so I couldn't give more than a few anyway, I'm afraid). The basics are AC steady state analysis, which can be done in any circuit simulator. Filters can be calculated from filter tables, but filters depend on termination resistance, for which this is an odd application (the DRV isn't a resistor). Network theory is a deep and high-level topic but the early work by Zobel, et al. (see archived BSTJ articles) may be approachable.

Comment: For EMC in general, consider Henry Ott's treatise; it may not be much of an introduction, but it could be studied over time as one builds understanding of the subject.

Comment: Thanks a bunch once again, Tim. I highly appreciate your contribution.

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider upvoting and accepting as answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, those components are for RF suppression, because the switching transients in a DC motor (from the commutator action) can create radio static.   They help the AM reception in the next room, not the motor.

D12 and D13 shunt the peak voltage-from-ground, which
limits the motor terminal voltage and protects "IC 10",
apparently.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense. And I was wondering if the schottky diodes also help re-directing the back EMF? if not would an extra flyback protection be required here?

Comment: @CoppersCopernicus The back-EMF is a consequence of rotation that never exceeds the normal motor drive voltage range, so it ought not require any protective measures.   An exception would be if the 'load' suddenly caused the rotor to speed up somehow.